# Grails - Saving multiple object, Rollback all object if one fails to save

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

I need to save multiple object at once, and rollback all if one object fails to save.
For example :

```
class Transaction {
  Item item;
}

class Item {
  date lastTransaction;
}
```

If I create new Transaction, I need to change lastTransaction value and save the item.

If I failed to save the item, I need to rollback the Transaction (vice versa).

Any ideas?

Comment: For transactions to rollback, you need to throw a RunTimeException

Comment: You might like to use a different name for your domain object (`BankTransaction` or something appropriate), otherwise you're talking about wanting to update a `Transaction` in a transaction but rolling back the transaction if the `Transaction` failed to update and your head will explode :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yuck. Don't throw exceptions to roll back transactions. You're incurring a pretty high cost to take advantage of a ***side effect*** where the transaction manager, assuming that a runtime exception means that you're not in control, automatically rolls back the transaction for you to keep you from doing more damage. It's a bit like being lonely and hitting yourself in the head repeatedly with a hammer so some EMTs and perhaps a nurse or a doctor will spend some time with you.

It's pretty easy to roll back a transaction, but unfortunately Grails doesn't expose any of this:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport

class FooService {

   def someMethod(...) {

      boolean somethingBadHappened = ...
      if (somethingBadHappened) {
         // roll back
         TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()
      }

      // ok, proceed
      ...
   }
}
```

And later you can check if the current transaction was rolled back with

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isRollbackOnly()
```

Note that this won't work in a controller since the transaction will have ended by that point.

Comment: Yes this is also works. But I need to grab the FieldError or ValidationException to display in .gsp page.
So, even if I use this, I still need to throw new Exception.

Comment: You can return the object that failed to save and call `hasErrors()`, `getErrors()`, etc. The exception is 100% unnecessary.

Comment: Here's a great resource that shows how expensive exceptions are: http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/ - imagine if they looked at Groovy exceptions, which have way more stack frames than regular Java exceptions.

Comment: I believe you were right. 
I will change my code, even if it looks a bit dirty without exception :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Burt - if throwing exceptions to rollback transactions is not considered good practice, I think the docs should be updated to say that (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession)

Comment: I have one last question, if I use setRollbackOnly(), why does the sequence id keeps incremented even if it's failed?

Comment: When you `save()` a new instance, the id value will be set from the sequence, and anything that gets flushed by Hibernate during the tx will be saved in the database's transaction queue. If the transaction rolls back the changes are discarded, but sequences aren't reset because gaps are ok, and another transaction might have already used a value near yours and resetting could result in non-unique ids.

Comment: I agree Grails documentation points in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service method and put your persistence logic in there. When you call `save`, if you specify `failOnError: true` then if there are validation problems an exception will be thrown and your transaction will be rolled back.

```
def myServiceMethod(...some parameters...) {
    ....
    Item item = new Item(lastTransaction: new Date())
    item.save(failOnError: true)
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(item: item)
    transaction.save(failOnError: true)
    ...
    return transaction
}
```

Also, have a read through of the [services section](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html) of the Grails docs.

Comment: Hi rcgeorge23, Thanks a lot for answering. My problem is solved :-)