# Grails: Store audit record regardless of success/failure?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, audit

In Grails, what is the recommended pattern to write an audit record for certain actions regardless of how the transaction ends? Example: Online user registration attempt that may fail for a number of reasons.

Basic assumption, business logic is confined to transactional service methods.

Underlying uncertainty: Should I abort a transaction by throwing a RuntimeException in the service? The Grails guide kind of implies so, but [Burt Beckwith once said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138173/grails-saving-multiple-object-rollback-all-object-if-one-fails-to-save) (with a chuckle, I'm sure) it's like hitting yourself with a hammer to get yourself some care.

Given long-winded logic with several checks, it's convenient to throw an exception when a conflict is detected. The overall transaction should be rolled back, but an audit record should be written all the same.

N.B. There are several audit Grails plugins, but they record changes to committed domain objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our application, we use the [Platform Core](https://grails.org/plugin/platform-core) plugin for this. Basically, when some interesting things happen, such as:

- User logs in
- New user signs up
- User creates a new instance of some business object
- User deletes something
- etc...

We fire an event, like this:

```
event(
    'myApp.activity', [
    userId: userService.currentUser?.id,
    detail: [name: "some useful information about this activity", timestamp: new Date(), ...],
    activityType: ActivityType.CREATED,
    action: "create",
    ...
])
```

We can then define methods in another service class that listen for some of these events, e.g.

```
@Listener(topic="myApp.activity")
def audit(parameters) {
    //create an audit record for the thing that just happened
}
```

The benefits are

- it keeps cross-cutting stuff like audit logic away from the rest of your application's logic
- auditing is carried out in a separate thread (so it's not involved in the same transaction as the thing that fired the event)
- you can assign multiple listener methods to a single activity so you have another option for extending your application later

Comment: Clear and architecturally sound. I'll go for it!