# Grails: way to save a parent and children to database ONLY if all pass validation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a parent object that can only be created if children are valid. . Children can only reference parent by id after it has been saved (since id is auto incremented). SO I save the parent and then assign the parent to the children to save.
How do I rollback all the parent save and any child saves that have occurred if one child fails to be saved?

(This is taking place in a service layer)

```
 parent.save(flush:true);
 children.each{child->
     child.parent=parent;
     if(!child.save(flush:true)){
            //how to roll back all previous child saves if any AND 
            //initial parent save also
     }
 }
```

Comment: Make sure the above code is in a transactional method in a service and throw an unhandled exception. This will cause the transaction to roll back all saves done within the method.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Plain Exception or RuntimeException or does it matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter, any exception that isn't caught will do.

Comment: You shouldn't throw exceptions just to roll back transaction. Use transaction.setRollbackOnly() instead. explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21153225/5932498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you throw an uncaught exception in a transactional service the transaction will rollback everything. Something like this:

```
package com.example

class MyService {

    static transactional = true

    void myMethod() {
      parent.save(flush:true)
      children.each{child->
        child.parent = parent
        if(!child.save(flush:true)){
          throw new RuntimeException('Rollback')
       }
     }
    }
}
```

Personally I wouldn't use a `RuntimeException` in production code. I'd create my own exception and avoid filling in the stacktrace in this case. However, for example purposes the above demonstrates what you would want to do.